# Unable to create custom iso Ubuntu 22.04 using autoinstall

Tags: boot, kernel, 22.04, customization, cloud-init

I am trying to create a Single Ubuntu 22.04 custom iso from ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso using cloud-init configuration for autoinstallation.

I have my meta-data and user-data files in /cdrom/dxccore/inst folder.

My grub.cfg entry is
linux   /casper/vmlinuz quiet autoinstall ds=nocloud;s=/cdrom/dxccore/inst ---
initrd  /casper/initrd
With this, installation is proceeding normally it is not picking up the user-data configuration skipping the user-data file.

I have tried with the below entries also but still it is not working.
linux   /casper/vmlinuz quiet autoinstall ds='nocloud;s=/cdrom/dxccore/inst/' ---
initrd  /casper/initrd

I tried to make the below changes but still same issue.

linux   /casper/vmlinuz quiet autoinstall ds='nocloud;s=/cdrom/dxccore/inst/' ---
initrd  /casper/initrd
I am getting unknown kernel command line parameters error .

Attaching the user-data file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8bT5.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8bT5.jpg)

I want to know why it is giving Unknown kernel command line parameters error is coming up.

Comment: Are you trying to modify an Ubuntu Server (not Desktop) install iso for the goal of autoinstallation (non-interactive) on hardware (not VMs or Containers)?

Comment: Yes I am using Ubuntu server iso but I want the OS to be installed on VM as well on hardware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working fine with the below syntax

linux /casper/vmlinuz quiet autoinstall 'ds=nocloud;s=/cdrom/dxccore/inst/' ---
initrd /casper/initrd

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to modify the Ubuntu Server installer iso image. That won't work unless you are an expert.

Autoinstall of Ubuntu Server on hardware (bare metal) should use a separate media --like a USB stick-- for the cloud-init data and metadata files. This must also be formatted as an .iso so the installer can detect it's presence.

Autoinstall of a virtual Ubuntu Server system on top of an existing host is simpler: The cloud-init data and meta-data can be URLs or even plain host files.

- If using certain VM or Container hypervisors (like QEMU or LXD), lightweight cloud-images are available instead of using the install iso.
- Autoinstall of Ubuntu Desktop 22.10 and earlier cannot use cloud-init methods. The installer is different, and does not speak cloud-init. That is scheduled to change in 23.04.

See https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart for an example of how to create the separate media, and how to run a test install using a VM.

For frequent re-imaging or mass-installs on hardware, look at PXE booting: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/netbooting-the-live-server-installer/14510

Comment: But our requirement is to have one custom ubuntu ISO which can kickstart the installation using the configuration file like in ks.cfg for redhat and autoyast.xml in suse.

Comment: I have seen few websites like https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Make-Ubuntu-Autoinstall-ISO-with-Cloud-init-2213/

Comment: Where there is a procedure mentioned to create the custom iso but that is for Ubuntu 20.04 , I have followed the similar procedure . Can you help me if that is possible instead of using two ISO